# When creating a message box in python with def, it only shows the first letter of each string

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making a small and useless login system just to test out python and Tkinter. My code is:

```
from tkinter import *
import ctypes


def mbox(title, text):
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(0, text, title, 0)


def login():
    if entry_1 == "admin" and entry_2 == "admin":
        mbox("Success!", "Login successful!")
    else:
        mbox("Sorry...", "Login unsuccessful.")

root = Tk()

label_1 = Label(root, text="Name")
label_2 = Label(root, text="Pass")
entry_1 = Entry(root)
entry_2 = Entry(root)
button_1 = Button(root, text="Login", command=login)

label_1.grid(row=0)
label_2.grid(row=1)

entry_1.grid(row=0, column=1)
entry_2.grid(row=1, column=1)

button_1.grid(row=2, column=0, rowspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Yet when i run this code and click the button, the mbox shows as the title: 'S' and the text: 'L'

I honestly am unsure why this should happen, is my def set up wrong?

Comment: It's because in C strings are just pointers to each subsequent letter.

Comment: I would suggest `import tkinter as tk` rather than `import *`

Comment: `if entry_1 == "admin" and entry_2 == "admin"` doesn't do what you think it does. `entry_1` and `entry_2` are widgets, not strings, so that condition will never be true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you posted as "fixed" does not work. `entry_1` and `entry_2` are widgets and don't have a value. To get the text in the entry boxes you need to use `entry_1.get()` and `entry_2.get()`. Also I suggest using a dictionary to check for username and passwords like this post does. Your code would look like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox

Dict={"admin":"admin"}

def mbox(title, text):
    tk.messagebox.showinfo(title, text)


def login():
    if entry_1.get() in Dict and Dict[entry_1.get()] == entry_2.get():
        mbox("Success!", "Login successful!")
    else:
        mbox("Sorry...", "Login unsuccessful.")


root = tk.Tk()

label_1 = tk.Label(root, text="Name")
label_2 = tk.Label(root, text="Pass")
entry_1 = tk.Entry(root)
entry_2 = tk.Entry(root)
button_1 = tk.Button(root, text="Login", command=login)

label_1.grid(row=0)
label_2.grid(row=1)

entry_1.grid(row=0, column=1)
entry_2.grid(row=1, column=1)

button_1.grid(row=2, column=0, rowspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

I've managed to fix the code, while taking on your suggestions:

```
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.messagebox


def mbox(title, text):
    tk.messagebox.showinfo(title, text)


def login():
    if entry_1.get() == "admin" and entry_2.get() == "admin":
        mbox("Success!", "Login successful!")
    else:
        mbox("Sorry...", "Login unsuccessful.")


root = tk.Tk()

label_1 = tk.Label(root, text="Name")
label_2 = tk.Label(root, text="Pass")
entry_1 = tk.Entry(root)
entry_2 = tk.Entry(root)
button_1 = tk.Button(root, text="Login", command=login)

label_1.grid(row=0)
label_2.grid(row=1)

entry_1.grid(row=0, column=1)
entry_2.grid(row=1, column=1)

button_1.grid(row=2, column=0, rowspan=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Thanks for you guys' help!

Comment: I still don't see how that's working though entry_1 and entry_2 are widgets so it should always be False. Use `.get()` to obtain the text value `if entry_1.get() == "admin"`